# horizontal rule / line inside a multicolumn field

Tags: tables, rules

I need to have a horizontal line inside a multicolumn cell. When the horizontal line is just in one cell this is without problems possible, when spanning, with multicolumn, over say 2 cells I get an error message:

```
! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
<argument> \hrule

l.22 \end{longtabu}
```

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{3}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 \\\cline{1-3}
Column 1&\hrule
&Column 3 \\\cline{1-3}
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 \\\cline{1-3}
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{4}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hrule
 }&Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

The resulting image (going in batchmode on error):

[image]

In the second row of the second table I would like a line in the combined columns 2 and 3 like shown in the first table in row 2 column2.

I use the tabu package, I know that there are some problems with this package but I use the older version of Tex Live and for the 2019 version I use the "saved" tabu package (and friends).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `\hrulefill` instead of `\hrule`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{3}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 \\\cline{1-3}
Column 1&\hrule
&Column 3 \\\cline{1-3}
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 \\\cline{1-3}
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{4}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\hrulefill} &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My problem is nor getting ride of the message but that I cannot give a `\hrule` inside a `\multicolumn` and I need to have a horizontal line here. Just removing the `\hrule` leaves still the missing line problem. Note: inside the table `\hline` doesn't work at all

Comment: @albert Refer the updated answer...

Comment: Small understatement, this is much better.

Comment: I had to post a follow up question:  interaction between \usepackage[table]{xcolor} and \hrulefill (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506221/interaction-between-usepackagetablexcolor-and-hrulefill)

Comment: Fine, its fine to go with a new question, but accept this answer is helpful for this question...

Comment: I was going to accept this answer but I'm just waiting if there are others with other ideas.