# interaction between \usepackage[table]{xcolor} and \hrulefill

Tags: tables, rules

This is a followup question on [horizontal rule / line inside a multicolumn field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506211/horizontal-rule-line-inside-a-multicolumn-field/506213#506213)
In the later the problem regarding the horizontal line was solved but whe using the

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

the required line does not span the combined cells but just the first:

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{4}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hrulefill
 }&Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

This results in the wrong output as the horizonatl line is only in the first part of the combined cells:

[image]

The expected output is:

[image]

I use the tabu package, I know that there are some problems with this package but I use the older version of Tex Live and for the 2019 version I use the "saved" tabu package (and friends).

Comment: The issue can be reproduced with `\begin{tabular}{*4c}` instead of `longtabu` and loading only `colortbl` (which is loaded by the `table` option of `xcolor`).

Comment: You should report this issue to the author of colortabl. It is either a feature or a bug.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I removed my initial comment as I realized that colortbl would give the same problems. Thanks for the reply on loading the complete xcolor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `colortbl` uses `fill` glue where the LaTeX kernel only uses `fil` glue.

You need a “more infinite” `\hrulefill`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\hrulefilll{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hskip 0pt plus 1filll\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [c]{*{4}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3             & Column4 \\ \hline
Column 1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hrulefill} & Column4 \\ \hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3             & Column4 \\ \hline
\end{longtabu}

\bigskip

\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [c]{*{4}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3              & Column4 \\ \hline
Column 1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hrulefilll} & Column4 \\ \hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3              & Column4 \\ \hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Compile with an old TeX Live.

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation @egreg thanks for sharing ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Do you think the problem is a feature or a bug? Should I make an issue at https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/issues ?

Comment: @albert A feature.

Answer (score 0):

When not using:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

but

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

the line looks lie to be complete again.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{4}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hrulefill
 }&Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
Column 1&Column 2&Column 3 &Column4 \\\cline{1-4}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange…Just loading `xcolor` produces a `! Missing } inserted.`error message for me.

Comment: Strange I don't get an error. I'm using (for my tests) MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6839 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)

Comment: I have MiKTeX 2.9.7140 and tabu from 11-1-2019. For me, it looks like an incompatibility between `xcolor` and `tabu`. Furthermore, using something like `\color{red}` inside a cell with ordinary text, without loading xcolor, compiles just fine but… produces no text colouring.

Comment: The newer tabu versions have some problems that is why I wrote the last line in my question. The problem is widely discussed here and also indicated at https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu. Looks like you run in some of those problems as you use a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Happily enough, usually I do without tabu!